# Some users have been denied acess to the SQL Server athough they have valid logins

Tags: sql-server

Some users in my company are unable to connect to one of our servers though they have valid logins.

Below is the error that I am getting in the SQL server error log.

> Message Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11.
>   Login failed for user ''.
>   Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: 10.10.101.134]

When I elevate the privilege to sysadmin they are able to access the server; otherwise; they are unable to login to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I once read **[an excellent article on this by Mr. Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/19/sql-server-login-failed-for-user-reason-token-based-server-access-validation-failed-with-an-infrastructure-error/)**

Quoting answer from blog below

1. If you are seeing login failure for machine account, then you may want to give permission to machine account. You need to run T-SQL like below (replace domain and machine name)

   `CREATE LOGIN [<Domain>\<Machine account>$] FROM WINDOWS`
2. If it’s a windows domain user account, then it needs to have connect permission

   `GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [DOMAIN\User]`
3. If few cases, account is part of a group (or many groups) then you need to make sure there is no “DENY” permission inherited via group membership.

   `SELECT sp.[name],sp.type_desc
   FROM sys.server_principals sp
   INNER JOIN sys.server_permissions PERM ON sp.principal_id = PERM.grantee_principal_id
   WHERE PERM.state_desc = 'DENY'`
4. If the message only comes with local connectivity and same account works fine remotely then it could be a UAC issue. This means that Elevation is required to connect properly, but you do not see any of the normal prompts to elevate. To use elevation (while launching the SSMS to connect to a locally running instance of SQL) Right click->Select “Run as administrator”.

**Depending on the situation, out of four, any option might work.**